# What solutions exist for attaching files to post before post was created?

Tags: database, architecture

For example we click a button **add news**

Go into tab **images** and start uploading images via AJAX.
Then write some interesting content and click a **save news** button.

Db tables for this example will be something like

```
NEWS   |
--------
id     |
--------
content|

ATTACHMENTS |
-------------    
id          |
------------- 
news_id     |
-------------
file_name   |
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As a simple option, try introducing another table to map the images to news. 
A `one-to-many` relationship, say something like this:

```
+----+---------+----------+
| ID | news_id | image_id |
+----+---------+----------+
|  1 |      10 |       41 |
|  2 |      10 |       42 |
|  3 |      12 |       43 |
+----+---------+----------+
```

Then, before the post was created but after the images were uploaded, have the IDs of the images in a `hidden field` before saving the news post itself:

```
<input type="hidden" name="image_ids" value="41,42">
```